# XML Serialize with catel

Tags: catel

Is it neccessary to have the complete namespace in every model I save to xml.

```
<MyModel xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyProject.Models">
```

Is it possible to disable this?

and is it possible to save a property of this model as attribute instead as element?

```
<MyModel MyProperty="5" > 
  <AnOtherProperty>10</AnOtherProperty>
</MyModel >
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the `OptimalizationMode` to `XmlSerializerOptimalizationMode.PrettyXml`.

Comment: Hi Geert. 
This makes no difference.
At startup I warmup my types and set this property

    var xmlSerializer = SerializationFactory.GetXmlSerializer();
    xmlSerializer.OptimalizationMode = XmlSerializerOptimalizationMode.PrettyXml;
    xmlSerializer.Warmup(typesToWarmup);

Later I call 

    MyWarmupedClass.Save(_filePath, SerializationMode.Xml);

Comment: ?? I don't understand why my text is not formated. Ident code block wit four spaces!!! On my question it works.

Comment: You can't use code blocks in comments. Please provide a repro on the issue tracker, then we can take a look. See http://www.catelproject.com/support/issue-tracker